# sklearn fit() function's mean

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm study about machine learning.
While study about sklearn, I got some question about fit function's mean.
As I know, that function makes model match to data.

What is the different after fit function?
(a = [1, 2, 3] vs KNeighborsClassifier.fit([a]))
(a = [1, 2, 3] vs PolynomialFeatures.fit([a]))

I want to know result of KNeighborsClassifier.
fit([a]) and a = [1, 2, 3].
So I use list(KNeighborsClassifier.fit([a])).
 But is not work.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand the question at all. Is "a" supposed to be the data? The "vs" lines don't really make sense for a comparison. On the one side you have a simple list of integers, on the other a model that has been fitted to that data. There is nothing to compare! Do you mean to plug new data into an already trained model and see the outcome of the classification? Then you might be looking for the "predict" function, not "fit".

Comment: a is kind of data. Just a example express in list. And vs use mean like 'between' in sentence. Not a code.

Comment: And my question is I want to know difference between original data and after fit function data.

Comment: As the answer by @Amirov describes: The original data will be used to train the mapping (to a classifier for example). The data itself won't change at all with that function! Nevertheless, if you feed the data through the trained model with the "predict" function, you will get a prediction for each sample contained in the data. But since you've trained on the data, this will give you only an idea of how good your (potentially overfitted) prediction is on data seen during training. Predicting unseen data will then give you a measure of generalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fit function is used to fit a model to training data. The model is trained using the training data, and the resulting model parameters are stored in the model object.

The result of calling KNeighborsClassifier.fit([a]) is a trained KNeighborsClassifier object, which you can then use to make predictions on new data. This is why you cannot use the list() on it as it is not a list.

To make predictions with a trained KNeighborsClassifier object, you can use the predict method. For example:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

X = [[0], [1], [2], [3]]
y = [0, 0, 1, 1]

clf = KNeighborsClassifier()
clf.fit(X, y)

pred = clf.predict([[2.5]])
print(pred)
```